# Boost/sort Elasticsearch results based on array intersection

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm interested in including a list of numeric ids in my index, like:

`some_ids: [1234, 2345, 3456,...]`

Then I'd like to pass another array of ids in with my search such that the more ids that the search array has in common with the indexed array, the more relevant the result is.

Ideally an array of ids that is the intersection of the search array and the indexed array could be returned with the result.

The number of ids in each array will typically be under 100, but could grow to thousands on both the index side and they query side in worst cases.

Anyone know if this is feasible and what a good approach might be?

Thanks in advance!

~Brian

Answer (score -1):

You can make a bool query with should, like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
           {
               "terms": {
                  "field_ids": [
                     "123456",
                     "987654"
                  ]
               }
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

With this command, you'll get the score, and by default ES order by score :)

The mapping:

```
PUT test_ids/_mapping/my_type
{
    "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "field_ids" : {
                "type":"integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Gustavo.  Do you think this will scale to hundreds of thousands of documents with up to thousands of field_ids in the documents and in the search?

Comment: I'm wondering if I should instead take a sorting approach, in which I index and search against simpler, flat fields, then sort the results based on the array intersection first, search score second.  I might not even need to index the field_ids in the ES index.  I'm not sure what the sort syntax would look like, I might need to code it myself in a script.